# An introductory book on philosophy of language and logic?

Tags: logic, reference-request, philosophy-of-language, modal-logic, introduction-to-philosophy

I tried self teaching philosophy of language, logic, modal logic but I am lost as a headless chicken. Can anyone help me please? I have a full time job, but I can take an hour everyday and learn a bit. Is there any introductory book on these topics?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SE. But I'm afraid I have to tell you that your question is not really appropriate for this site. The guidelines say:- "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here." Read the rest as well. You should also think carefully about whether your project is really a good idea.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it falls under the guideline that says:= "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are happy to learn from books, here are some suggestions.
If you want an introduction to elementary logic aimed at philosophers, John MacFarlane's "Philosophical Logic: A Contemporary Introduction" is a good start.

On modal logic, the standard text is Hughes and Cresswell, but it's fairly heavy going for a beginner. You might be better off with Rod Girle's "Modal Logics and Philosophy".

For the philosophical issues concerning the concepts used within logic, Anthony Grayling's "An Introduction to Philosophical Logic" is good.

For a general introduction to the philosophy of language, try Szabo and Thomason, "Philosophy of Language".